# Pandas Datathinning: How can I effectively reduce the number of points in a Series while still preserving the original overall trend?

Tags: python, pandas, compression, resampling

I have some time series data and a parameter of interest in a dataframe - there are hundreds of thousands of rows, but for a large portion of them there is only an extremely small change (if any at all) from one point to the next. When looking at the trendline these points become unimportant - is there a good way to reduce the size of my series by trimming out some of the unimportant points?

**Moreover, what would you call this process? (so I can go search/learn more about it) Data thinning? Resampling?**

I've found something called the [Ramer Douglas Peucker Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) which seems to do pretty much what I have in mind, but I'm not sure if it would be better to just sample from my existing data, grabbing more points at times where the change is more rapid, and less points when it is constant.

TLDR: I want to remove the number of rows in a series, keeping more points then the data is changing more and keeping less when the data isn't changing much. [image]

Answer (score 1):

@JaPa

I would start with native Pandas functionality prior to venturing out in more nuanced algorithmic approaches.

Two options come to mind, without seeing your actual data.

Option 1 - to apply a rolling window or moving average to smooth out the data and reduce noise.

```
# calculate rolling mean with window of 10 days
df_rolled = df.rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).mean()
```

[reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Option 2 - use resampling techniques, such as averaging or taking the maximum or minimum value of the data over a certain time interval.

```
# resample to monthly frequency and calculate mean
df_resampled = df.set_index('date').resample('M').mean().reset_index()
```

[reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

If you have attempted these before and you are looking for something new, you could try **PAA (Piecewise Aggregate Approximation)** available in the [tslearn package](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It works by shortening a time series by dividing it into windows of equal size and replacing the values within each window with their mean.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I guess I can clarify: I know how to implement a rolling average and have done so in the past, but in this particular case, it isn't necessarily what I'm looking to do. I'm not concerned about smoothing the data so much as I am trying to reduce the number of data points required to represent the time series behavior. (In fact, for a local max/min, I especially want to keep that info rather than smoothing it out).

Comment: I'll also add, I'm not going to be doing advanced analytics - mostly I just need the visual representation of the data, but some of the plotting functions I am using have limits on the # of data points that are allowed.

Comment: @JaPa Thank you for clarifying, how I interpret your requirements, as a Time Series Dimensionality Reduction exercise. I'd take a look at Singular Value Decomposition or you could take a look at reshaping the data to handle the variance and cluster the data points, as shown [here - using tslearn](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auto_examples/clustering/plot_kmeans.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-clustering-plot-kmeans-py).